# Azure Recovery Backup Agent Not Registering

Tags: azure

I re-installed Azure Backup Agent for Windows Server 2008. Now whenever I try to register the agent I am getting this message:

> Failed to re-enable existing scheduled backup settings. The server must be registered with Microsoft Azure Backup before this operation can be performed.

As you can see from the error message, it is asking me to register the server while I am already trying to register it.

[image]

The only solution I can think of is that I delete the old settings and then try again. Can someone please guide me in the right direction, where are the backup agent settings kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server was already registered with the Azure Recovery Services. To fix the problem. Go to https://manage.windowsazure.com and select Recovery Services -> your_vault -> Registered Items -> select the server -> Allow Re-registration. The follow message will appear. Select 'Yes' to fix the issue.

> Are you sure you want to allow re-registration for ?
>
> When you allow re-registration, the your_server_name server will be allowed to register again with the backup vault. Allow re-registration only if certificate issues exist on the server or if you rebuilt the server. If you want to access previously created recovery points, make sure that you register the server with the same backup vault.

Answer (score 0):

You should to uninstall everything and reinstall everything again.

Follow these steps (Taken from [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ef5ab47-276d-46e2-b90e-f00e1c5db3a8/could-not-install-azure-backup-agent-on-windows-2012-essentials-r2-already-installed?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup))

#### Uninstall

1. Go to the "APPLICATIONS" tab page
2. In the Add-ins Tab, select "**Microsoft Azure Backup**"
3. Then click "**Remove the add-in**" (right Task tab)
4. Make sure you checked "**Remove the backup agent**"
5. Then click Remove.

#### ReInstall

1. Go to "HOME" -> "Get Started" -> "SERVICES" page
2. Click "**Integrate with Windows Azure Backup**"
3. Click the link "**Click to download Windows Azure Backup integration module**" on the right section.
4. Save ".wssx" add-in file to local folder.
5. Trigger the downloaded file, and restart dashboard after the installation.